# Keeping Track of which enum is selected?

Tags: java, enums

```
/**
 * All the states in the game.
 */
public enum State {
    START_MENU,
    PLAYER_ONE_MENU,
    PLAYER_ONE_CATEGORY,
    PLAYER_TWO_MENU,
    PLAYER_TWO_CATEGORY,
    WIN_SCREEN,
    LOSE_SCREEN,
    PLAY_SCREEN
}
```

That is the enum i have made for a hangman game i am designing. However I am new to enums but someone suggested I use enums for game states. However I do not know how to track which state the player is currently on. Could someone explain a way to track which state is selected?

Comment: Better rename `States` to `State` as just one of those values is held in a variable of that class.

Comment: BTW, use underscores to separate words in constants, and increase readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a variable of type `States` with the current state.

```
class Player {

 States currentState=States.STARTMENU;

 void doSomething() {
  switch (currentState) {
   case STARTMENU:...;
   case PLAYERONEMENU:...;
   //etc
  }
 }

 void playMenu() {
  if (currentState==States.PLAYMENU) {...}
 }
}
```

Comment: `States currentState = States.STARTMENU;`.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Java Doc for Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html):

> **valueOf(Class enumType, String name)**
>
> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified name.

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable with the type of the enum, for example:

```
State var;
var = State.PLAYER_TWO_MENU;
```